# removing duplicates from a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read a file, make a list of words and then make a new list of words removing the duplicates.
I am not able to append the words to the new list. it says none type object has no attribute'append'

Here is the bit of code:

```
fh = open("gdgf.txt")
lst = list()

file = fh.read()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()

file = file.split()
for word in file:
    if word  in lst: 
        continue
    lst = lst.append(word)

print lst
```

Comment: Get rid of `lst =`; `.append` doesn't return anything. Also, a `set` is more efficient for this.

Comment: `if word  in lst: continue`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python `append` will return `None`.So `set` will help here to remove duplicates.

```
In [102]: mylist = ["aa","bb","cc","aa"]

In [103]: list(set(mylist))
Out[103]: ['aa', 'cc', 'bb']
```

Hope this helps

In your case

```
file = fh.read()
```

After this `fh` will be an empty generator.So you cannot use it since it is already used.You have to do operations with variable `file`

Answer (score 1):

`append` appends an item in-place which means it does not return any value. You should get rid of `lst=` when appending `word`:

```
if word in lst:
    continue
lst.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing your list with the return value of the `append` function, which is not a list.  Simply do this instead:

```
lst.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` is inplace append, it returns `None` (as it does not return anything). so you do not need to set the return value of `list.append()` back to the list. Just change the line - `lst=lst.append(word)` to -

```
lst.append(word)
```

---

Another issue, you are first calling `.read()` on the file and then iterating over its lines, you do not need to do that. Just remove the iteration part.

---

Also, an easy way to remove duplicates, if you are not interested in the order of the elements is to use set.

Example -

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3]
>>> set(lst)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

So, in your case you can initialize `lst` as - `lst=set()` . And then use `lst.add()` element, you would not even need to do a check whether the element already exists or not. At the end, if you really want the result as a list, do - `list(lst)` , to convert it to list. (Though when doing this, you want to consider renaming the variable to something better that makes it easy to understand that its a `set` not a `list` )

Answer (score 1):

`append` modifies the list it was called on, and returns `None`. I.e., you should replace the line:

```
lst=lst.append(word)
```

with simply

```
lst.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fh=open("gdgf.txt")

file=fh.read()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
lst = []
file=file.split()
for word in file:
    lst.append(word)
print (set(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

`append()` does not return anything, so don't assign it. `lst.append()` is 
enough.

***Modified Code:***

```
fh = open("gdgf.txt")
lst = []

file=fh.read()
for line in fh:
     line = line.rstrip()

file=file.split()

for word in file:
     if word  in lst: 
         continue
     lst.append(word)

print lst
```

I suggest you use  [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) , because it is used for unordered collections of ***unique elements.***

```
fh = open("gdgf.txt")
lst = []

file = fh.read()
for line in fh:
     line = line.rstrip()

file = file.split()

lst = list( set(lst) )

print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by reading and adding the words directly to a set. Sets do not allow duplicates, so you'll be left with just the unique words:

```
words = set()

with open('gdgf.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      for word in line.strip():
          words.add(word.strip())

print(words)
```

The problem with the logic above, is that words that end in punctuation will be counted as separate words:

```
>>> s = "Hello? Hello should only be twice in the list"
>>> set(s.split())
set(['be', 'twice', 'list', 'should', 'Hello?', 'only', 'in', 'the', 'Hello'])
```

You can see you have `Hello?` and `Hello`.

You can enhance the code above by using a regular expression to extract words, which will take care of the punctuation:

```
>>> set(re.findall(r"(\w[\w']*\w|\w)", s))
set(['be', 'list', 'should', 'twice', 'only', 'in', 'the', 'Hello'])
```

Now your code is:

```
import re

with open('gdgf.txt') as f:
   words = set(re.findall(r"(\w[\w']*\w|\w)", f.read(), re.M))

print(words)
```

Even with the above, you'll have duplicates as `Word` and `word` will be counted twice. You can enhance it further if you want to store a single version of each word.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to this problem can be more succinct:

```html
import string

with open("gdgf.txt") as fh:
    word_set = set()
    for line in fh:
        line = line.split()
        for word in line:
            # For each character in string.punctuation, iterate and remove
            # from the word by replacing with '', an empty string
            for char in string.punctuation:
                word = word.replace(char, '')
            # Add the word to the set
            word_set.add(word)
    word_list = list(word_set)
    # Sort the set to be fastidious.
    word_list.sort()
    print(word_list)
```

One thing about counting words by "split" is that you are splitting on whitespace, so this will make "words" out of things like `"Hello!"` and `"Really?"` The words will include punctuation, which may probably not be what you want.

Your variable names could be a bit more descriptive, and your indentation seems a bit off, but I think it may be the matter of cutting/pasting into the posting. I have tried to name the variables I used based on whatever the logical structure it is I am interacting with (file, line, word, char, and so on).

To see the contents of 'string.punctuation' you can launch iPython, import string, then simply enter `string.punctuation` to see what is the what.

It is also unclear if you *need* to have a list, or if you just need a data structure that contains a unique list of words. A set or a list that has been properly created to avoid duplicates should do the trick. Following on with the question, I used a `set` to uniquely store elements, then converted that `set` to a `list` trivially, and later sorted this alphabetically.

Hope this helps!